# How to optionally enable cdef class arbitrary attribute assignment at runtime

Tags: cython

Lets say I have a `cdef class`:

```py
cdef class MyClass:
    # declare some cdef attributes here
    cdef dict __dict__
    def __cinit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__ = {}
        # do some other init stuff
```

I normally want to be able to add attributes to `MyClass` instances, so I have a `__dict__` attribute.

I also want to have a way to tun that off at runtime. I tried adding a `__setattr__`:

```py
    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        if not _STRICT:
            object.__setattr__(self, attr, val)
            return

        if hasattr(self, attr):
            object.__setattr__(self, attr, val)
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                "Cannot set attribute '" + attr + "' on " + 
                self.__class__.__name__ +
                ' because that attribute does not exist!'
            )
```

where `_STRICT` is a variable that can be toggled at runtime.
This trick works great in pure python, but with the extension type I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: can't apply this __setattr__ to MyClass object
```

The [docs](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/special_methods.html#general) seem to indicate that I should be able to make a custom `__setattr__`, but I seem to be running up against [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-April/034605.html) change which prevents using `object.__setattr__` to set attributes on built-in types. I tried using `super().__setattr__` but it errors in exactly the same way.

Is there some other way to set attributes on Cython extention types that I'm missing, or is there some other way to do this?

Comment: If this issue is still accurate doesn't seem possible - https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1301.  Potentially could hack around it by directly assigning into `__dict__` in your `__setattr__` override.

Comment: @chrisb the issue you link to has been fixed - adding `__dict__` does let you assign arbitrary attributes. However `super().__setattr__` and `object.__setattr__` don't seem to exist. Your assignment to `__dict__` seems to work fine, so looks like the right answer.

Comment: @DavidW @chrisb Assigning into `__dict__` in `__setattr__` doesn't solve the problem because doing that does not update the `cdef` declared attributes. The point of this question was to find a way to *at runtime* enable or disable the ability to add non-`cdef` attributes to an instance.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It might be worth mentioning that detail in your answer (just because it's an important point and not immediately 100% obvious).

Comment: @DavidW agreed, it was one of the first things I tried and since you both thought it would work, it may be a common pitfall. Updated answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got past the block that I [referenced](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-April/034605.html) by calling the C api directly:

```py
from cpython.object cimport PyObject_GenericSetAttr

...

cdef class MyClass:

    ...

    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        # in non-strict mode, we always update the attribute or
        # add it to the instance even if it is not already present
        if not _STRICT:
            PyObject_GenericSetAttr(self, attr, val)
            return

        # If we got here, we are in strict mode, and we only
        # allow attribute setting if the instance already has
        # that attribute
        if hasattr(self, attr):
            PyObject_GenericSetAttr(self, attr, val)
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                "Cannot set attribute '" + attr + "' on " + 
                self.__class__.__name__ +
                ' because that attribute does not exist!'
            )
```

NOTE: One of my attempts to solve this was to just update the `__dict__` as suggested in the comments. This doesn't work because `cdef` attributes are not stored in the instance `__dict__`. If you update the dict with `__dict__[attr] = val` it will happily put that into the dict, but `getattr(instance, attr)` will not return your update if the attr was declared with the `cdef` keyword.